# Check if string starts with X letter in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I check that string starts with a given letter in Ruby?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`String#start_with?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/String/start_with%3F) method

```
'String'.start_with? 'S'
 => true
```

Also you can list possible variants of beginning

```
'String'.start_with? 'E', 'S'
 => true
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex

```
str.match /^X/
```